# jquery ui sortable - Dragging not working correctly when using containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

I'm having an issue with jquery ui sortable where I can't drag certain items (i guess based because of the height of the item elements)

```
<div class="container">
<fieldset>
    <legend>handle 1 THIS CAN'T BE DRAGGED BELOW HANDLE 2</legend>
    <div>blah<br /></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>handle 2 BUT I CAN DRAG THIS ABOVE HANDLE 1</legend>
    <div style="display: none">blah<br /></div>
</fieldset>
```

```
$(".container").sortable({
   axis: 'y',
   handle: '> legend',
   containment: 'parent',
   /*cursorAt: {top: 1},
   start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
      $(this).sortable('refreshPositions');
   },*/
});​
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/ADyhR/10/
EDIT: It seems to work in jquery ui 1.8.9. is it just a bug in 1.8.18?

the commented out javascript lines are things that i've tried but haven't worked, but i figured I might just be slightly off in how i was using them.

Comment: funny that if you take bottom one fieldset , pull it over top one and put it back, margin for bottom one returned and you can pull top one below, but after you release button , margin return to the former state and you cant move it below again.

Comment: seems to be a bug of dragable

Answer (score -1):

You may use the [**`tolerance`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance) option and set its value to `tolerance: "pointer",`. I have updated your DEMO and created a [**NEW DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/ADyhR/21/).

Here is the JS code that works **with `tolerance` option added**:

```
$(".container").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    tolerance: "pointer",
    handle: '> legend',
    containment: 'parent',
    /*cursorAt: {top: 1},
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
        $(this).sortable('refreshPositions');
    },*/
});
```